# Mercurial Hgflow: Adding a new feature to a release branch?

Tags: mercurial, workflow, release

From what I've read adding new features to a release is discouraged.

Now suppose the boss really wants that new feature in the current release, how would you handle this?

I can think of two options, which I believe are not supported by hgflow:

- option 1:

  1. branch from dev at the branching point of release/x.x
  2. finish feature
  3. merge to release/x.x
  4. close feature branch
- option2:

  1. branch from latest point in release/x.x
  2. release/x.x/featName
  3. finish feature
  4. merge to release/x.x
  5. close feature branch

How would you deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the only difference is that option 1 uses the version from the moment of release and option 2 takes code added after the version was released. If that's the case, it totally dependeds on whenether you want this new code to be included when you release the new feature or not. If you are unsure, take option 1.

Answer (score 4):

The [newer versions of hgflow](https://bitbucket.org/yujiewu/hgflow/wiki/Home) (0.9.4 is the latest) by yujiewu support Option2. The syntax is something like the following:

```
# In release/x.x branch
hg flow release/x.x start boss_wants_new_feature
# Now you create a branch called release/x.x/boss_wants_new_feature.

(a bunch of commits to implement the feature)

# In release/x.x/boss_wants_new_feature branch
hg flow release/x.x finish
```